# What are the advantages to using the various shorthand methods in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Suppose I have an array of person objects, and I want to use lodash to find the one named 'Joe'.
I can do it using the `_.matches` iteratee shorthand:

`const joe = _.find(persons, {name: 'Joe'});`

and I can do it using the `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand:

`const joe = _.find(persons, ['name', 'Joe']);`

What are the advantages of using each of these methods (or other methods)?

Comment: `persons.find(v => v.name === 'Joe')`

Comment: Although I haven't downvoted, it begs the question "define 'better'"

Comment: @Chris - that's the why part. I'd like people to reason about their preference, so I can decide.

Comment: @zerkms Array.prototype.find as a new addition to ECMAScript and is not supported by all browser (e.g. IE). That's one of the reasons to use lodash. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @splintor I understand, but it doesn't suit the SO format unless we can better quantify what 'better' means. In other words, if 3 people answer below, which do I upvote if it's just a preference? I would say either reframe the question as "Are there any perf advantages to using the matches shorthand?" Or even, "what are the advantages to using the various shorthand methods in lodash" - then we can upvote a comprehensive answer consisting of comparisons as opposed to "I like this because x"

Comment: @splintor and lodash is not natively supported by any browser at all. If you're fine using a 3rd party library - there is really no reason to not use the modern standard with a polyfill backup.

Comment: @zerkms - There is one reason - convenience. Instead of checking for each method you use if it is supported or if you (or someone from your team) already provided a polyfill for it, using one library that is consistent and documented is more convenient.
(and another one: Using lodash _.find(), you don't need to check that persons is not null before calling it)

Comment: @Chris Agreed - edited. Thanks!

Comment: @splintor you don't need to check anything - the es2015 standard is 1.5 years old (so for the new projects it should be used by default). Not sure why people deliberately prefer to not use it.

Comment: @zerkms Maybe because people need to support IE, which doesn't support es2015?

Comment: @splintor there are transpilers. It is a really weak justification to use ancient standards. But I'm not insisting - I don't mind if people deliberately limit themselves with no good technical reason. I'm (and a lot of developers around) supporting IE and using es2015 even since before it was finalised, think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no better variant. Several variants of input data made for easy chaining without extra data mutations. I always use this variant

```
const joe = _.find(persons, {name: 'Joe'});
```

**Update**

advantage of array like shorthand - it can be usefull for find by nested object like

```
const joe = _.find(persons, ['transaction.user.name', 'Joe']);
```